# How do you get a list of all available list values for a field in NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I would like to set a value into a list field in NetSuite, but I am finding that I receive an error if that value does not exist.

**How can I search for all values to check if the value I am trying to place is good or not? I would also be open to this just failing silently without showing an error and instead just not populating the value.**

> ERROR_CODE:INVALID_KEY_OR_REF MESSAGE:Invalid custentity_esc_industry
>   reference key Wholesale. STATUS_TYPE: ERROR

```
try {
  //var rec = scriptContext.newRecord;
  var integrationFieldValue = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue(integrationFieldName);
  if(integrationFieldValue != null && integrationFieldValue != ''){
    scriptContext.newRecord.setText({
      fieldId: actualFieldName,
      text: integrationFieldValue
    });
  }
} catch(e){
  log.error({
    title: "setNonIntegrationFieldValue() has encountered an error.",
    details: e.message
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the getSelectOptions in SuiteScript 2.0. It will return an array of the first 1000 available options.

For Example:

```
var objRecord = record.load({
   type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
   id: 275 
});
var objSublist = objRecord.getSublist({
   sublistId: 'item' 
});
var options = objField.getSelectOptions({
    filter : 'C',
    operator : 'startswith'
});
```

For more details, you can search 'Field.getSelectOptions' in Netsuite Help center